# Entity Framework core: Relation with two not primary keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an old project where I cant make changes to the database, I'm creating a new API using .net core 3.

I have two tables `page` and `Note` that have `PageId` and `BookId` in common, so that each Note has one Page with the same BookId and PageId

```
public class Note
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public int PageId { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
   [Key]
   public int MainId { get; set; } // this is the primary key
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public int PageId { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

PageId is not the primary key for Page and has duplicate values. 
I want to get the page by the note id, I'm doing it like this:

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetPageByNoteId(int noteId)
 {
        var note = await db.Notes.FindAsync(id);
        var page = await db.Pages.Where(x => x.BookId == note.BookId && x.PageId == note.PageId)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return Ok(new {note,page});
 }
```

Is there a way to do this with one database hit?

---

Update:

The primary key for page is `MainId` but it should be `PageId` and `BookId` together but I cant make changes to the database, If I can make changes to the database I would make the following to the Page table:

- remove the `MainId` column
- Make `PageId` and `BookId` the primary key

then I can do this:

```
      modelBuilder.Entity<Note>(entity =>
       {
                   entity.HasOne(Note => Note.Page)
                         .WithOne(page => page.Note)
                         .HasForeignKey<Note>(note => new { note.PageId, note.BookId});

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
  public class Note
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Page Page { get; set; }
    }

    public class Page
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Note Note { get; set; }
    }
```

And in your DB Context class.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);
...
         builder.Entity<Note>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Page)
            .WithOne(x => x.Note);
```

Now you can do like below.

```
 var page = (await _context.Notes.Include(x => x.Page)
                                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)).Page;
```

This solution is for when you have one to one relations from note to the page. if it is one to may you can change the Pages property to collection.

Comment: You are ignoring the `BookId`, as I mentioned each note relates to one page by two keys (BookId, PageId). let's say I want to get the page for a note that has BookId = 1 and PageId = 1, but there is another note with BookId = 3 and PageId = 1, your answer will get all of them and I have to get the one with BookId = 1 on the client. the Page table has too many records with the same pageId.

Comment: i notice you said one to one relationship between note and page, So I updated the answer

Comment: @tamimabweini i still dont get the full context. Let me ask you one more question. How did you created model. From your question it look like you were using database first approach. That means those model were auto scaffold from EF . if so models which you listed on question exactly exist same on your project too. What is the relation of this table inside OnModelCreating method?